# Delete multiple rows based on select

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm trying to make a trigger that will remove rows from one table based on select in another table

table `operatorpositions`
columns `operator`, `line`, `pos`

table `positiontags`
columns `line`, `position`, `tag`

table `operatortags`
columns `operator`, `tag`

My trigger looks like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER removeOperatorPosition AFTER DELETE ON operatorpositions
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM operatortags WHERE gen = NEW.operator 
            AND tag = (SELECT tag FROM positiontags WHERE position = NEW.pos AND line = NEW.line);            
    END;
```

Problem is there can be multiple tags for one position, so subquery will return multiple rows. How do I need to change this so it will work with multiple tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you you want to delete all tags.
so try to replace your = before the subquery with `IN`

```
CREATE TRIGGER removeOperatorPosition AFTER DELETE ON operatorpositions
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM operatortags WHERE gen = NEW.operator 
            AND tag IN (SELECT tag FROM positiontags WHERE position = NEW.pos AND line = NEW.line);            
    END;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE TRIGGER removeoperatorposition AFTER DELETE
ON operatorpositions
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM operatortags
  WHERE  gen = new.operator
         AND tag IN (SELECT tag
                     FROM   positiontags
                     WHERE  position = new.pos
                            AND line = new.line);
END;
```

Changing from `=` to `IN` operator should work on subqueries returning multiple rows

Comment: Yep, feel stupid it was so easy :) Also had to change `new` to `old` because im deleting

Answer (score 3):

A more efficient way to do it is to use a join -

```
CREATE TRIGGER removeOperatorPosition AFTER DELETE ON operatorpositions
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        DELETE ot
        FROM operatortags ot
        INNER JOIN positiontags pt
            ON ot.tag = pt.tag
        WHERE ot.gen = OLD.operator 
        AND pt.position = OLD.pos
        AND pt.line = OLD.line;            
    END;
```